# Select Table Row in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I'm trying to achieve selecting just only one row at a time in my React Material App. My problem now is that it is highlighting many rows. I only need to highlight/select one row at a time.

Pls check this codesandbox link

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/highlightselect-rows-react-material-4o58c)

**CODE**

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);

const selectFood = (event, food) => {
  const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(food.name);
  let newSelected = [];

  if (selectedIndex === -1) {
    newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, food.name);
  } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
    newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
  } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
    newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
  } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
    newSelected = newSelected.concat(
      selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
      selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
    );
  }

  setSelected(newSelected);
};

const isSelected = row => selected.indexOf(row.name) !== -1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just select a single row -
then this would work definitely ( no need of complex code which you have written )

```
const selectFood = (event, food) => {
    let newSelected = [food.name];
    setSelected(newSelected);
  };
```

Working link - https://codesandbox.io/s/highlightselect-rows-react-material-8ejbc?file=/demo.js:1016-1123